# Setting-up OpsCenter gives: scp /tmp/.. Permission denied

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I'm trying to setup OpsCenter by adding my localhost Cassandra node (for testing).
The login credentials I used for SSH has sudo/root rights, nevertheless I get the error:

> scp: /tmp/tmpXInRfq: Permission denied

I can understand that SCP protocol (which is apparently used in OpsCenter) can't do such thing like executing a 'su' command.
But what do I wrong?

opscenterd.log:

```
2014-08-08 23:05:59+0200 []  INFO: Testing SSH connectivity to localhost
2014-08-08 23:05:59+0200 []  INFO: Testing SSH login to localhost
2014-08-08 23:05:59+0200 []  INFO: SSH connectivity/login test succeeded
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 []  INFO: agent_config items: {'cassandra_log_location': '/var/log/cassandra/system.log', 'thrift_port': 9160, 'jmx_pass': '*****', 'thrift_ssl_truststore': None, 'rollups86400_ttl': -1, 'api_port': '61621', 'use_ssl': 0, 'rollups7200_ttl': 31536000, 'kerberos_debug': False, 'storage_keyspace': 'OpsCenter', 'thrift_user': '', 'provisioning': 0, 'metrics_ignored_column_families': '', 'metrics_ignored_keyspaces': 'system, system_traces, system_auth, dse_auth, OpsCenter', 'jmx_user': '', 'cassandra_install_location': '', 'kerberos_use_keytab': True, 'rollups300_ttl': 2419200, 'thrift_pass': '*****', 'metrics_ignored_solr_cores': '', 'metrics_enabled': 1, 'kerberos_use_ticket_cache': True, 'thrift_ssl_truststore_type': 'JKS', 'rollups60_ttl': 604800, 'ec2_metadata_api_host': '169.254.169.254', 'kerberos_renew_tgt': True, 'thrift_ssl_truststore_password': '*****'}
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 []  INFO: Starting provisioning process
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 []  INFO: Starting installation phase of cluster provisioning
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 []  WARN: HTTP request http://localhost:61621/alive? failed: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 []  INFO: Beginning install of OpsCenter agent to localhost
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 [] ERROR: Installation failed: scp to u'localhost' failed
      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/Agents.py", line 1042, in _provisionNode

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/Agents.py", line 1133, in _installAgent

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/SecureShell.py", line 135, in perform_scp

2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 []  WARN: Marking request 068afb4c-d862-4265-856f-84103c35dddb as failed: Failure installing agent on localhost.
     Error output:
            scp: /tmp/tmpXInRfq: Permission denied

     Exit code: 1
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 []  INFO: Successfully installed agent and dsc on node localhost
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 []  WARN: Marking request 'install stage' (d9bd09cd-0ae4-41b3-ba25-f03adfe988dc) as failed: Failure installing agent on localhost.
     Error output:
            scp: /tmp/tmpXInRfq: Permission denied

     Exit code: 1
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 [] ERROR: Installation stage failed: Failure installing agent on localhost.
     Error output:
            scp: /tmp/tmpXInRfq: Permission denied

     Exit code: 1
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 []  WARN: Marking request 'provision' (148d05e8-a1aa-49c8-ac2d-a1e523b79009) as failed: Installation stage failed: Failure installing agent on localhost.
     Error output:
            scp: /tmp/tmpXInRfq: Permission denied

     Exit code: 1
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 [] ERROR: 
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 [] ERROR: Cluster provisioning failed: Exception: Installation stage failed: Failure installing agent on localhost.
     Error output:
            scp: /tmp/tmpXInRfq: Permission denied

     Exit code: 1
2014-08-08 23:06:00+0200 [] ERROR: Failed to provision cluster: Cluster provisioning failed: Exception: Installation stage failed: Failure installing agent on localhost.
     Error output:
            scp: /tmp/tmpXInRfq: Permission denied

     Exit code: 1
```

[image]

What do I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Melroy van den Berg

Comment: Installing DataStax Enterprise does work (which creates a separate user/group called 'cassandra'). It also installs a datastax agent, Cassandra itself, DevCenter (for developing) and OpsCenter for visual monitoring the cluster.


But still I don't know why the installation failed using the Community version (a.k.a. Cassandra cluster) instead of Enterprise Cluster?

Comment: FYI: As somebody said on IRC my /tmp is probably mounted without 'exec' permissions.

Answer (score 1):

OpsCenter uses a temp file on the OpsCenter machine itself to facilitate ssh.  So rather than being a problem with the login credentials not having sudo rights, I believe it may actually be that the user running OpsCenter does not have permissions to create tmp files at:

    `/tmp/tmpXInRfq`

On the machine running OpsCenter.  Can you confirm if the user running OpsCenter can touch a file in that location?

Thanks.