# Opscenter is unable to install agents due permission denied to /tmp

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

O am not able to install agents on 10.0.0.29 IP through opscenter. It says below error. The user is pavan and this user is having sudo access. Opscenter is unable to install the agents and I'm not able to use opscenter to monitor the cassandra nodes. I was able to remove tmp folder using sudo access of the user 'pavan' but I'm not sure what is missing here.

I went through question asked, but I could not get answer on this. Please help me to resolve this issue. 
[Setting-up OpsCenter gives: scp /tmp/.. Permission denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/619120/setting-up-opscenter-gives-scp-tmp-permission-denied)

```
Installations Failed
Some agent installations failed:

- 10.0.0.29: Failure installing agent on 10.0.0.29.
Error output:
scp: /tmp/tmpZaSXoY: Permission denied

Exit code: 1
```

**opscenterd.log**

```
2014-08-11 18:04:15-0500 []  INFO: Testing SSH connectivity to 10.0.0.29
2014-08-11 18:04:15-0500 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Beginning install of OpsCenter agent to 10.0.0.29
2014-08-11 18:04:15-0500 [Test_Cluster] ERROR: Installation failed: scp to '10.0.0.29' failed
      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/Agents.py", line 1133, in _installAgent

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/SecureShell.py", line 135, in perform_scp

2014-08-11 18:04:15-0500 []  WARN: Marking request 2b69e5c5-5d5f-40ae-a762-26128b2c9c6f as failed: Failure installing agent on 10.0.0.29.
     Error output:
            scp: /tmp/tmpZaSXoY: Permission denied

     Exit code: 1
2014-08-11 18:04:15-0500 []  WARN: Marking request 10a4bcd7-1de2-4a93-9f92-216975ec1d8d as failed: Failure installing agent on 10.0.0.29.
     Error output:
            scp: /tmp/tmpZaSXoY: Permission denied

     Exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This was only affecting one of my servers, but I ended up installing "datastax-agent" through my package manager:

Debian: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/install/opscManualInstallAgentPkgDeb.html

RHEL: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/install/opscManualInstallPkgRpm.html

Others: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/install/opsc-agentInstallManual_t.html